# Job failed only on scheduler

Tags: oracle, etl, datastage

I'm using infosphere DataStage of IBM for loading data in ETL processes.

I have some problem with one of my jobs.

This job scheduler twice a month, and when it run automatic by the tool - it get an oracle error:

> ORA-00813 : object no longer exists

But when we run it manualy after it failed - there is no error at all and it's finished fine.

I tried to run the query in oracle directly and it just fine.

That problem happend twice, and always after the failure - it run good with manual execution.

any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: anybody have an idea?

Comment: Sounds like a timeout on the Oracle side, if it was me I would be investigating timings from datastage for the job run times before it fails, then also request that the Oracle DB's run a stats pack for the period that the job was running and 'timed out'. I'd also review with them if there are any autonomous tasks killing processes off (backups etc?)

Comment: I already found the problem. there was another process that run in same time and make truncate to one table that thus process read from. After I executed audit on the schema i found it. thanks a lot!